# Scala: oddness adding to a Map

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have just noticed that whilst I need clarifying parens when adding a pair to a map, I don't need them when doing a re-assignment:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM, Java 1.6.0_18).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

Get me some values

```
scala> var n = Map.empty[Int, String]
n: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map()
```

Trying to add to the map with no clarifying parentheses:

```
scala> n + 1 -> ""
<console>:30: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: (Int, ?)
              n + 1 -> ""
                  ^
```

Fails as I expected it to. But doing the same via a re-assignment does not:

```
scala> n += 1 -> ""

scala> n
res12: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> "")
```

What is going on? Why is this not failing? Is `scalac` adding parens itself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just a precedence issue.  `+` and `-` have the same precedence.  `=` is lower.  So Scala sees `(n + 1) -> ""` in the former case, and `n += (1 -> "")` in the latter (which is then transformed to `n = (n + (1 -> ""))` according to the normal rules for assignment operators.

Answer (score 4):

According to [scala reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (6.12.4):

> **Assignment operators are treated specially in that they can be expanded to assignments if no other interpretation is valid.** ... The
>   re-interpretation occurs if the following two conditions are fulfilled.
>   1. The left-hand-side l does not have a member named +=, and also cannot be converted by an implicit conversion (§6.26) to a value with a member named > +=.
>   2. The assignment `l = l + r` is type-correct. In particular this implies that l refers to a variable or object that can be assigned to, and that is convertible to a value with a member named +.

(1) [Immutable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html) Map has no member named `+=` ([mutable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html) has) and AFAIK, has no implicit conversions to something with that *and* assignment is definitely type correct (2): n defined as a *`var`iable* and has member `+`.